# Monit - stop service and stay stopped?

Tags: monit

I have a daemon which runs via the usual init.d/service scripts.

I have monit running which ensures these daemons are restarted if they crash.

I have a request that 'service foo stop' should stop the deamon, and because it was explicitly stopped, not a crash, monit should not restart it. How can I achieve this with monit?

I could have the service script's stop() routine call 'monit unmonitor' but this seems circular and wrong.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 30):

I think you should use `monit stop foo` instead of `service foo stop`. That way Monit is aware that the service didn't crash -- and won't restart it.

Answer (score 7):

There is a `MODE` param for that:

> Monit supports three monitoring modes per service: active, passive and manual.
>
> Syntax:
>
> MODE 
>   In active mode (the default), Monit will pro-actively monitor a service and in case of problems raise alerts and/or restart the service.
>
> In passive mode, Monit will passively monitor a service and will raise alerts, but will not try to fix a problem by executing start, stop or restart.
>
> In manual mode, Monit will enter active mode only if a service was started via Monit

From here: https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#SERVICE-MONITORING-MODE

This way if you manage services via runit or upstart and just want to use monit for alerts and dashboards you simply set for all such services `mode` to `passive`.

For example:

```
check process heka with pidfile /etc/sv/myservice/supervise/pid
    start program = "/usr/bin/sv start myservice"
    stop program = "/usr/bin/sv stop myservice"
    mode passive
```

If you need to enable/disable that online but not permanently -- please refer to other people's answers, they are fine.

Answer (score 2):

The model is:
Monit runs as a service by init.d and therefore controlled (stop/start/restart) by init.d . (Others, please me if I am wrong).
Applications that require to be monitored are handled by monit.

Therefore, such applications should be only controlled i.e. stop/start/restart via monit.
monit

Answer (score 1):

```
SET ONREBOOT LASTSTATE
```

As per: https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#SYSTEM-REBOOT-AND-SERVICE-STARTUP